# how to show a Form and continue?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

i'm trying to make a console application with 2 Form classes. each Form only ever has one instance that's why i'm storing the instance in a static class.

## Goal

- it does some processing
- during which it may create and Show() a Form and immediately continue processing (during which it may create and Show() the other Form)
- the Main function interacts with the picturebox in one of the Form by calling the Form's functions
- i expect the application to simply end/terminate at the end of the Main function

## Problem

this almost works except that the Form seems to be "Busy" with something else:

- hovering over it shows the Busy cursor
- i can't move the Form either

## Attempts

- Application.Run(new Form1()) seems to hand over control to the Form. but i want it to continue in the Main function (as i mentioned).

## Code

here is an example that uses 1 of the 2 Forms:

Main function:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        // processing
        FormData.form.InvokeDraw();
        Thread.Sleep(10000); // simulate further processing
    }
}
```

static class:

```
class FormData
{
    public static Form1 form;

    static FormData()
    {
        form = new Form1();
        form.Show();
    }
}
```

Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void InvokeDraw()
    {
        pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)Draw);
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        }

        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        pictureBox1.Update();
    }
}
```

## EDIT:

i'm making an interpreter. the user can load a program as a text file. some of these programs can contain commands to draw something. writing to the console is also one of these commands. it didn't seem right to show forms when nothing is drawn. that's why it's a console application

Comment: Do you know this command: Application.DoEvents();

Comment: i've just tried to create a separate thread that only calls Application.DoEvents() in a infinite loop, but the form is still unresponsive

Comment: Why bother making a Console app behave like a WinForms application? Console apps don't have a message pump by default hence why your window is frozen. Sure you could probably add one but why? You don't say why you are doing this either, maybe tell us.  If you want a window make a WinForms app

Comment: i'm making an interpreter. the user can load a program as a text file. some of these programs can contain commands to draw something. writing to the console is also one of these commands. it didn't seem right to show forms when nothing is drawn. that's why it's a console application

Comment: Can the form exist if the console app is closed?

Comment: @George Vovos i wouldn't expect the form to exist after closing the console, but that would be acceptable

Comment: Then you could start a new Windows Form Application instead of showing a form...

Comment: @George Vovos: thanks. this seems like a good idea. how do you suggest handling multiple instances? i will probably go with this if there are no other suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Windows Forms project on your solution and add your form.

To run a new exe file use the Proccess class

```
if (IsWindowsFormsAppRunning() == false)
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"Path\windowsFormApp.exe");


private static bool IsWindowsFormsAppRunning()
{
   //update this function
   return false;
}
```

The are many ways to check if an app is already running,some simple some more advanced.
You will find a way to do this easily if you check this link

https://www.google.gr/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=iAYCVLLQN-bc8gf6_IHoDA&gws_rd=ssl#q=c%23+check+if+application+is+running

Comment: thanks. i will separate the forms from the console application

Comment: when i mentioned multiple processes i meant that my application can have multiple instances (an instance of the Form application for each console) and how the the console would know which Form application to communicate with. but i have that figured out now. i will use TCP to communicate and use the process ID of the Form application to decide on the port. which the console application knows from System.Diagnostics.Process.Id